# Removing all numbers from a string in C#, except for specific date sequences

Tags: c#, string

I am looking to clean Strings that are the title of images.  I want to remove irrelevant numbers, but preserve date sequences such as (i.e. 1923 or 2010) or relevant dates (i.e. 20/10/2012 or 12th June).

For example here I have used brackets to denote what I would like to remove:

> Central Station 1929 [12l89]
>
> [NZ1253] Bessie Pit Drift Mine
>
> Path Head 12th June 2012
>
> [4722] Greenfield 20/10/2012

In the example above 4722 would not be taken as a valid year, the dates would range from 1900 to the present day, so say anything beginning 19-- or 20-- and with two proceeding digits.

I understand how to remove all numbers using Regex as below:

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex trimmer = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\s\s+");
```

But am unsure how to preserve the others.

Comment: why isn't 4722 a valid date? or rather, when is a potential year not valid?

Comment: You have first define what are irrelevant numbers. From what you write I guess it is not only about dates but also about date ranges. Like @Default said, 4722 could be a valid year. You need to give us more details.

Comment: In this case the images will be in the 1900's or the 2000's and so anything else with regards the year would not be valid.

Comment: So where you want to remove `NZ1253` - if that instead said `NZ1953` you wouldnt want to remove it? and what about the `NZ` there marks it for removal? that its attached to a number without whitespace? I fear you're heading for a very long, unweildly regex!

Comment: I think you might be right.  The NZ would mark it for removal, but in some cases it might be another sequence of letters with numbers.  So anything that is not solely a date separated by white space.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would never do this with Regex, its going to be unreadable and will be wrought with bugs.

Instead I would take the input line by line, tokenize it, and supply any logic necessary as small, self contained, testable units (rules).

You could then use regex in a much more limited way within your "rules" - for example the regex:

```
[A-Z]+(19|20)\d{2}
```

would match `NZ1982` but not `NZ1253`.

Your rules would need to get fairly complex, a match for `12th` would need to look forward to the next token, if it finds something that looks like it could be a month name, look forward again and if it find the next token looks like a year then perform some logic.

If you can accurately define each of your rules, the code for each individual one is very manageable.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense.  I've never used REGEX before other than removing all numbers so I'm just getting to grips with it.  Is there a simple way to preserve specific cases such as the dates you mention above, but remove every other number and number with a letter attached.  i.e. remove NZ1253 or 43jk234i and preserve the REGEX for NZ1982?